# Trouble splitting out the city, state and zip from website

Tags: python, html-content-extraction

I can't seem to get the city, state, and zip located after the mailing address in the "br" tag to pull out. I have no issue getting any other information extracted.

```
element = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='th' and 'Mailing Address:' in tag.text)
        if not element:
            print(f"Mailing Address not found for {parcel_number}.")
            return None
        mailing_address = element.find_next_sibling().decode_contents()
        address_lines = mailing_address.split('<br>')
        address = address_lines[0].strip() # first line is the address
        city_state_zip_br = element.find_next_sibling('br') # find the br tag containing the city, state, and zip
        if city_state_zip_br:
            city_state_zip = city_state_zip_br.next_sibling.strip()
            parts = city_state_zip.split(', ')
            if len(parts) < 3:
                city = ""
                state = ""
                zip_code = ""
            else:
                city = parts[0].strip()
                state, zip_code = parts[1].strip().split(' ')
                zip_code = zip_code.strip()
        else:
            city = ""
            state = ""
            zip_code = ""
```

Here is the HTML code: You will have to scroll to the right to see the city, state and zip on the HTML code below.

```
<tr><th>Parcel Number:</th><td>1207250000015003</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Type:</th><td>Real</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Property Class:</th><td>2                  </td></tr>
    <tr class="active form-table-title"><th colspan="2">Location</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Address:</th><td>11875 HIGHWAY 43 N AXIS, AL 36505 </td></tr>
    <tr class="active form-table-title">
        <th colspan="2">
            Owner
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Name:</th><td>TOWER LOT 1 LLC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                </td></tr>
    <tr><th>Mailing Address:</th><td>P O BOX 336                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <br>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <br>BIRMINGHAM                                       , AL                  35201-0336
```

I got it to pull out the state and zip perfect but on the city its pulling in the address with it. Any suggestions?

print out looks like this:
city: 10163 KALI OKA RD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               EIGHT MILE
state: AL
zip_code: 36613-8790

New code:

```
mailing_address_lines = [line.strip() for line in mailing_address.split('\n') if line.strip()]
        address = mailing_address_lines[0] # first line is the address
        print(f"address: {address}")
        city_state_zip_pattern = r'^(.+?),\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)$'
        city_state_zip_match = re.match(city_state_zip_pattern, mailing_address_lines[-1])
        if city_state_zip_match:
            city = city_state_zip_match.group(1)
            state = city_state_zip_match.group(2)
            zip_code = city_state_zip_match.group(3)
        else:
            city_state_zip = mailing_address_lines[-1]
            address_parts = address.split(city_state_zip)
            if len(address_parts) > 1:
                city = address_parts[1].strip()
            else:
                city = ""
            city_state_zip_parts = city_state_zip.split()
            state = city_state_zip_parts[-2]
            zip_code = city_state_zip_parts[-1]
            address = address_parts[0].strip()
        print(f"address: {address}")
        print(f"city: {city}")
        print(f"state: {state}")
        print(f"zip_code: {zip_code}")
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see the value of the variables each step of the way so you know what you're actually working with. Or add more print statements to see. One possibility is that `mailing_address = element.find_next_sibling().decode_contents()` turned the `<br>` into a newline so `address_lines = mailing_address.split('<br>')` isn't working. The HTML you shared also doesn't have a <br> in it

Comment: It does you have to scroll to the far right of the mailing address. Sorry I tried to make that clear.

Comment: `city_state_zip.split(', ')` expects commas between city, state and zip, But the HTML doesn't have a comma between the state and zip, so `len(parts)` will be 2 and your code therefore sets `city = state = zip_code = ""`.

Comment: Posted new code above. Having trouble with /re and getting the address out of the city column.